# Como guardar dados apenas para leitura? Devo utilizar o SQLite nesse caso?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo (um *widget* na verdade) que mostra algumas frases na *home* do usuário. Tenho cerca de **1000 frases de 150 caracteres aproximadamente**, como vou armazenar isso? Nesse caso o uso de DB vale a pena?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem diversas formas que podem ser usadas e neste caso praticamente qualquer solução é viável. Você não deu maiores detalhes e nem requisitos, não é fácil responder isto principalmente sem incorrer em opiniões que não ajudam em nada.

## SQLite

Então tentando ser objetivo eu digo que [**eu usaria o SQLite**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101) sim. Não porque é a melhor solução, eu não sei se seria neste caso. Mas porque ela funciona bem hoje e provavelmente funcionará bem no futuro e porque provavelmente não há nenhum contraindicador para evitar o SQLite.

Claro que se o seu requisito for ter algo bem pequeno, que precise economizar cada *byte*, eu evitaria o banco de dados. Mas ele consome bem pouca memória, raramente é importante ter essa economia.

## Arquivo bruto

Talvez nem precise dele, talvez um arquivo mais básico seja suficiente. Manipular um arquivo bruto pode parecer muito simples mas também pode trazer complicadores inesperados principalmente se quiser evoluir a aplicação no futuro. Criar um formato pode se tornar complicado e por incrível que pareça mesmo que o formato seja tão simples quanto ter linhas (mais simples que o formato CSV) se você tiver familiaridade com banco de dados e não com manipulação de arquivos, o mais fácil é o que você já sabe. Um dos motivos do SQLite ter sido criado é para as pessoas não precisarem ter que lidar com arquivos brutos.

## Lista de dados interna no aplicativo

E se os dados do aplicativo nunca sejam atualizados sem que o aplicativo seja atualizado também talvez fosse o caso até de colocar as frases em uma lista na aplicação. Mas eu não pensaria nisto mesmo que a ideia seja esta porque você pode mudar de ideia no futuro (se fizer uma abstração pode ser uma boa ideia pra começar).

## Conclusão

Primeiro escolha o mais fácil, poderoso e flexível depois você pensa se precisa otimizar. O SQLite parece ser um canhão para matar passarinho. Mas não estou vendo nenhuma desvantagem real em usar esse canhão.

Fora estas observações importantes, só você pode dizer se vale ou não.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Na verdade o aplicativo é extremamente simples, ele apenas sorteia uma id e coloca na tela do usuário e depois de 10 minutos faz isso novamente. Penso que pra fins didáticos trabalhar com o SQLite será uma boa mesmo, além de que estou pensando em fazer uma nova versão no futuro. Obrigado.

Comment: Marcelo, você também pode usar SharedPreferences.