# Quando usar o SQLite?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite

Quando eu devo e não devo usar o SQLite?

Tenho um projeto que pretendo fazer não tenho ideia de quantas tabelas vão ser, mas acredito que mais de 15 com cerca de pelo menos mil linhas em algumas tabelas.

Seria viável fazer no SQLite?

Comment: Em que tipo de aplicação vc vai utilizar o `SQLite`?

Comment: Precisa dar mais detalhes sobre a aplicação.

Comment: Uma palestra que resume muito: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jib2AmRb_rk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SQLite vc usa se tiver a necessidade de ter um cenário de dados em modo desconectado.

Exemplo:
Vc tem o seu sistema corporativo (15 tabelas com 1000 registros cada), mas precisa ir à campo (ambiente desconectado) usar uma aplicação com dados do seu sistema.

Então, vc cria uma base SQLite no dispositivo que vai a campo (mobile, laptop, etc) e traz para essa base apenas dados que irão atender a necessidade desta ida à campo. E, assim que esse dispositivo retornar à rede corporativa, vc cria uma logica de sincronismo para trazer os dados do SQLite de volta para a base de dados principal.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!

Comment: Esta é uma simplificação do problema.

Comment: +1, não vejo por que de tantos downvotes,  sua resposta não está totalmente errada, algumas empresas utilizam o sqlite para isto, mas o sqlite tem poder para fazer muito mais, além de suportar ate 140TB ele é escolhido por vários por sua acessibilidade visto que  ele possui suporte nativo em vários devices Android, iOS, Windows Phone, Blackberry

Comment: A resposta leva uma pessoa que não sabe sobre o assunto acreditar que o SQLite é isso, o que é uma limitação do que ele pode fazer. Este é apenas um cenário. E nem é o cenário proposto na pergunta. A aceitação foi feita por um usuário que não entende o sistema e aceitou a primeira resposta postada sem entender o que isto significava.

Comment: @bigown, SQLite é um poderoso banco self-contained. Bancos assim são para fins específicos, quando não há cenário cliente-servidor (como vc mesmo disse). Então é ideal para trabalhar em ambientes desconectados (em campo). A pergunta foi: "Qdo usar ou não?" Respondi: "Use qdo precisar usar um BD com as características do SQLite.". O que foi que não te agradou?

Comment: Mas isto é incorreto, ou pelo menos limitador. Não é questão de me agradar ou não, é questão de dizer que o SQLite é feito para este cenário, quando na verdade ele é feito para vários. Eu uso o SQLite em ambiente cliente-servidor muito bem. E diversos outros cenários.

Comment: Mas @bigown, SQLite tem limitações. Vc mesmo citou "Ele não pode ser acessado confiavelmente de outras máquinas. Pode dar problemas.". No próprio [site](http://sqlite.com/whentouse.html) deles eles não recomendam cenários cliente-servidor.

Comment: Todo produto tem, mas ele não é nem de longe tão limitado como sua resposta indica. Eu coloquei essa citação na minha resposta, E mostrei que ela não é real. Basta saber fazer. Justamente este é o problema da resposta. Ela limita por desconhecimento de como usar a ferramenta do jeito correto nos diversos cenários possíveis. O fato de uma pessoa não saber como fazer não significa que não possa ser feito. O site não recomenda o uso direto, mas indiretamente é possível usar sem problema algum. E de fato é usado e eles recomendam em um cenário cliente-servidor, que é o website.

Comment: @bigown, citando do site oficial: "SQLite strives to provide local data storage for individual applications and devices./SQLite se dedica a fornecer armazenamento local de dados para aplicações individuais e dispositivos." - Ambiente desconectado, como eu respondi. É para isso é que é feito, e é para isso que é para ser usado.

Comment: @bigown, usar SQLite para website, apenas se vc hospedar o BD no mesmo host do website (no site ele diz que o site oficial é feito assim, host compartilhado). Diferente disso, será que ser criado um middleware (ex:API) para satisfazer. Arquiteturalmente, isso é ruim. Server de aplicação deve ser diferente do server de repositório. E neste ambiente, SQLite não atende.

Comment: Mas esse é o problema, você está pegando uma frase do que está lá isoladamente, não está lendo o site todo, nem vendo os que as pessoas fazem de fato. E está ignorando o que eu estou dizendo aqui. Você está tirando as coisas do contexto para dar um resposta errada. Programação é achar solução, não é ficar lento fragmentos de texto para se conformar e dizer que não tem solução. O problema da resposta é justamente esta atitude de se apegar a um detalhe como se ele definisse o todo.

Comment: Agora você começou despejar as baboseiras do "isso é certo, isso é errado", aí alguém pergunta porque e a resposta é "porque eu li em algum lugar que é assim". As coisas precisam ser usadas de acordo com fatos não com achismos, de acordo com receitas sem contexto. 99,99% dos sites possuem os bancos junto ao servidor HTTP. O mesmo vale para outros tipos de aplicação. Não que eu ache que deva, mas se precisar criar um middleware, crie, pelos motivos certos. Não tem nada errado com isto. Eu nunca falei que o SQLite atende todos os cenários. Atende quase todos. Você disse que ele atende só um!

Comment: Fora a incoerência de dizer que middleware é ruim e que servidor de aplicação e repositório devem ser separados. Primeiro isso tudo é regrinha boba que não olha o contexto, não busca solução, e depois o middleware é justamente para fazer esta separação.

Comment: @bigown, "99,99% dos sites possuem os bancos junto ao servidor HTTP." só se for dos 100% que vc conhece. Isso é uma péssima prática. Aplicação e base de dados tem que ser separados SIM. Eles possuem necessidades diferentes e se comportam diferentes. Em nenhum momento eu disso ou quis dizer que middleware é ruim, eu disse que, é ruim decidir por usar middleware para acertar um cenário inadequado. E middleware é para fazer integração, e não separação.

Comment: Não vou perder tempo com você que gosta de vomitar "boas práticas". Eu sou pragmático, eu não sigo receitas de bolo. Eu produzo soluções de acordo com as necessidades. Fique com suas boas práticas sem sentido, eu fico com soluções reais. Teorias não resolvem problemas. Tanto que as pessoas não seguem o que você está dizendo, a não ser nos raros casos onde elas cabem ou quando a pessoa só gosta de seguir receitas sem olhar o contexto. Não é necessário um canhão para matar passarinho. Mas se você gosta disto, pode usar nas suas "soluções", não vai me atrapalhar nada.

Comment: Uma pena ver que alguém tão supostamente influente aqui no SO pregue que boas práticas, arquitetura e responsabilidade DevOps sejam baboseiras.

Answer (score 20):

Antes de começar usar um ferramenta você deve estudá-la profundamente. E depois de estudá-la terá informações para decidir por conta própria se ela é viável para seu caso ou não. Não confie em pessoas aleatórias na internet para dizer para você o que é bom ou não para você.

Se você estudar o SQLite certamente chegará [nessa página](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). Ela diz onde o SQLite pode ser usado. Em resumo:

- Dispositivos móveis e embarcados
- Formato de arquivos
- "Pequenos" websites
- Análise de dados
- Cache para dados corporativos
- Banco de dados apenas no lado do servidor
- Arquivamento de dados
- Substituto para operações com arquivos comuns
- Bancos temporários ou internos
- Substituto para outros SGDBs em tarefas de teste e demonstração
- Treinamento em banco de dados.

Lá diz onde **não** deve usar:

- Aplicações cliente-servidor ([tem como usar se souber fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2371/101))
- Websites de grande volume (lá fala em 1% dos sites, minha experiência mostra que é mais raro ainda)
- Conjunto de dados absurdamente grandes (mas é raro quem tem esse volume todo)
- Alta concorrência (o maior problema dele, mas poucos possuem essa necessidade)

Ou seja, o SQLite é adequado para quase todos os casos. E os casos onde ele não é adequado, a pessoa saberá, porque aí o problema é tão complexo que alguém inexperiente não estará envolvido. E se isto acontecer, a escolha errada do banco de dados será um problema pequeno perto dos outros que ela cometerá.

Claro que ele pode não te agradar, mas aí é outro problema. Eu uso o SQLite sempre que eu posso. Ele não é tão completo em recursos quanto outros bancos. Ele é ótimo para armazenamento e relacionamento básico. Em geral, os recursos dos outros banco de dados podem parecer ótimos no começo, mas é preciso aprender tudo e usar corretamente. Muitas vezes ter apenas o básico torna o trabalho mais simples sem perder funcionalidade importante. A maioria dos recursos existentes em produtos mais "potentes" são apenas facilitadores que podem ajudar ou atrapalhar. Eles não estão ali sem cobrar um preço.

O seu caso é extremamente simples e não deve ter problemas. Mas é preciso analisar como os dados serão acessados. Haverá grande concorrência? Duvido, então acho que não precisa se preocupar com isto. O acesso será por uma aplicação na mesma máquina? Isto é importante. O SQLite não se dá bem em acessos sendo feitos por outra máquina.

Ele não pode ser acessado confiavelmente de outras máquinas. Na prática á raro dar problema, mas pode acontecer. A solução é ter uma aplicação na máquina que o acesse e permita que outras máquinas se comuniquem com esta aplicação (veja o *link* acima). Por isto websites funcionam bem. O servidor HTTP e o código do website seguem justamente este modelo. Porque as pessoas não seguem o mesmo modelo para outros tipos de aplicação? Provavelmente porque seguem receitas de bolo e não pensam fora da caixa. Ou talvez porque não sabem como fazer.

Esta é a real decisão se deve usá-lo ou não. O volume de dados é secundário.

Então estude o produto para entender as limitações que ele possui em facilidades extras, em volume de concorrência (real), e acesso direto remoto. Sabendo disto saberá onde pode usar ou não. O [site oficial](http://www.sqlite.org/) é muito informativo.

[Um exemplo de uso do SQLite em alta escala](https://blog.expensify.com/2018/01/08/scaling-sqlite-to-4m-qps-on-a-single-server/). Algumas pessoas não o usam, e acham que ele não escala, que não pode ser usado em quase todos os cenários no lugar de soluções mais completas. Ele só não é bom com muita concorrência de escrita e para ferramentas auxiliares ao banco de dados. Curiosamente essas pessoas costumam acreditar em NoSQL que costumam ser piores de leitura que o SQLite. As pessoas precisam pensar fora da caixa, investigar antes de fazer afirmações que atingem sua credibilidade.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Para uma facilita com o uso deste banco tem o `com.orm.SugarRecord;` ajuda bastante na criação das tabelas.. e para leitura, alteração e deleta os dados. [Site Do sugar](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)

Comment: É pode ser útil, mas é limitado a uma utilização específica dele.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza dei uma espiada, e parece muito mais complexo do que usar a interface nativa dele (dificilmente vai ter coisa mais fácil de usar que a interface nativa do SQLite que já tem tudo pronto). Pra eu entender melhor, quais seriam as vantagens dessa sua indicação, em relação à nativa?

Comment: Obrigado a todos!

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza mas já adianto que até gostei da abstração das coisas sem usar SQL. Para certas coisas pode ser interessante (mas não como substituto geral para as funções nativas).

Comment: @Bacco, em algumas funcionalidade, é útil, **mas não como substituto geral para as funções nativas**, por exemplo em criação de tabelas, eu simplesmente crio minha classe o sugar si vira para gera a tabela no banco... Bom mais para falar sobre funcionalidade de um ou de outro seria algo para uma pergunta e resposta mais elaborada.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza claro, só perguntei pra ver se tinha algum ponto em especial que você recomendasse. Mas ta aqui separado para eu ler melhor depois. Vou tentar entender onde pode se encaixar bem essa recomendação.

Comment: @Maniero o excesso de análise não pode se tornar uma barreira para a execução?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues o excesso de execução não pode ser prejudicial pra um bom resultado? Cada um escolhe o que acha melhor, eu jamais vou pelo caminho pior porque entrega mais rápido. Eu entrego qualidade. Isso passa por performance boa, custo mais baixo, usabilidade melhor, operacionalização mais fácil, e simplicidade geral. Claro que isso tem um custo inicial pra aprender fazer. Em geral fazer de qualquer jeito é a desculpa de quem não quer ou não pode aprender certo, até porque o certo sempre passa por ser mais fácil, depois da curva de aprendizado ultrapassada.

Answer (score 1):

O SQLite pode ser usado sempre que você tem de armazenar dados localmente de forma estruturada e resistente a corrupção. O código do SQLite é considerado um dos melhores em lidar com arquivos locais de modo a minimizar a chance de perda de dados, quem estuda o tema é aconselhado a estudar o código dele, então é preferível mesmo usar SQLite a tentar escrever código de manipulação de arquivos, mesmo em se tratando de dados simples como uma configuração de aplicação.