# Como amazenar informações estáticas sem usar banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Como armazenar informações estáticas sem utilizar o banco de dados?

Por exemplo, vamos dizer que eu possuo um texto numa página, que não tem necessidade de alterações com frequência, e pra evitar usar recursos do servidor e/ou deixar o carregamento da página mais rápido e também com opções de edição por "campos" como num banco de dados, existe algum *plugin* PHP ou algo eficiente que eu possa fazer?

Comment: Não invente a roda , no máximo pesquise por NoSQL https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Comment: A pergunta pode não pedir por uma boa prática, mas é perfeitamente válida.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

A melhor forma é usar um banco de dados. [Use o SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101) e seja feliz. Ele tem todas vantagens que procura e nenhuma das desvantagens que não deseja. Qualquer outra alternativa de usar arquivos por conta própria será pior. Mesmo outros bancos que trabalham de forma análoga ao do SQLite dificilmente é o que procura, ainda que também funcionem.

Em alguns casos onde praticamente não tem escrita e não tem colunas, não precisa de processamento, pode fazer em arquivo normal. Não parece ser o caso.

Uma alternativa para economizar recursos do servidor, se é que precisa disto mesmo, é usar o banco de dados só para armazenar os dados para gerar as páginas estaticamente. Se a página muda com pouca frequência, não tem partes dinâmicas (exceto partes que sejam carregadas sob demanda no cliente) e é acessada com muita frequência, crie o arquivo HTML quando ocorrer a atualização do banco de dados e mantenha ela para acesso estático.

Usar PHP não será eficiente. O consumo de recursos dele é pior que o uso de um banco de dados. Quanto menos coisas fizer no PHP, melhor. Claro que nem sempre é possível. Se for necessário mesmo, avalie se precisa ter algo em arquivo separado. Tem situações que a manutenção é tão rara e só o programador a fará que compensa até deixar tudo no código PHP mesmo. É o que o WordPress faz com algumas coisas. Reforço, tem casos.

Answer (score 3):

Para prototipação ou uso caseiro (fiz uma ferramenta para uso próprio e não quero me preocupar com qualidade), não há problema algum em usar um arquivo estático no disco.

Uma abordagem de implementação consistente para você armazenar um conjunto nomeado de valores que mudam com pouca frequência é armazenando tudo num arquivo JSON no disco com as funções [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) e [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Um exemplo de JSON num cenário onde uma página tem um texto e um título:

```js
{
    "texto": "Conteúdo da página",
    "titulo": "Título da página"
}
```

A vantagem disso é que mesmo a manipulação do arquivo pode ser feita manualmente sem grandes riscos, já que o formato é amigável para ser lido e modificado por humanos.

Aliás, esta técnica é comumente usada em produção para ler configurações, que geralmente são somente leitura.

O risco de usar arquivos no disco é se você modificar o arquivo de forma concorrente, por exemplo, se dois usuários tentaram atualizar o texto ao mesmo tempo.

As desvantagens de armazenar em arquivos em relação ao banco de dados é que falta controle transacional para garantir integridade e atomicidade, logs, histórico dos dados, flexibilidade para consultas diversas e por aí vai. Num projeto sério, sempre use um banco de dados para armazenar dados importantes do usuário, independente do tipo de banco utilizado.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma diferença entre Banco de Dados e Sistema Gerenciador de Banco de Dados.

O Banco de Dados é uma coleção de base de dados, basicamente você armazena todos os seus dados em um banco de dados, o diferencial é como você insere, manipula e retira dados de lá, este é o papel do Sistema Gerenciador (SGBD).

Se você quer armazenar dados sem o uso de um SGBD você vai precisar criar um seu. Isto pode se resumir em abrir um arquivo, escrever os dados e fechar o arquivo, entretando você estará disperdiçando as propriedades de Sistema Distribuídos que alguns SGBDs oferecem (se não todos), além do chamado propriedade ACID (banco de dados relacional) e BASE (banco de dados não relacional ou NoSQL).

Basicamente você pode ter um arquivo apenas para você escrever e deixar ali em um cantinho se você quiser, mas tenha ciência que você precisará trabalhar principalmente na atomicidade (proteger seus dados de falhas) o que dará bastante trabalho.

Minha sugestão: use um banco de dados relacional ou um NoSQL, veja qual melhor atende as suas necessidades, se você não for usar muito um dado em específico, não use, os SGBDs são inteligentes o suficientes em relação a isso, no caso do banco de dados relacional existe o conceito de Materialized View, você poderia tirar proveito disto. Se você for usar muito um dado com frequência, use, eles também são espertos para isso e facilita o acesso ao seu dado. Eles também oferencem ROLES (privilégios de acesso), acessos concorrentes, RAIDs, tudo isso você perde ao não utilizar um SGBD, além de que, se você utilizar um método próprio de manipulação de dados, você teria que ensinar isto a toda a sua equipe.

Answer (score -5):

sql faz coisas demais pra uma simples consulta.
e ainda considero lerda demais em comparação a outros mecanismos de E/S em arquivos.
acho que , como dito acima, usar um arquivo, e usá-lo para escrita leitura é o melhor