# SQL Incorporado no C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Tenho uma aplicação em C# que usa um banco de dados MySQL com Entity Framework. Entretanto, o tamanho do banco é ridiculamente pequeno, de modo que não acredito que valha a pena ter um servidor de banco de dados MySQL apenas para rodar esta aplicação.

Qual seria abordagem para que o banco de dados ficasse incorporado na aplicação, de forma que ela pudesse ser executada sem estar conectada a nenhum servidor?

E como eu transportaria os dados do banco de dados para esta nova solução?

Comment: Oi @Felipe, acho uma boa idéia neste caso usar o SQLite, ele é um arquivo (extensão .db) e tu usa as referencias dele no C#, não fica rodando nenhum serviço, você pode as bibliotecas [aqui](https://sqlite.org/download.html) ou também [aqui](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) e para visualizar uso o [SqliteExpert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html) que tem a versão free e a paga..

Comment: Oi Marco! Me pareceu uma excelente ideia! Obrigado pela dica! Abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Qual seria abordagem para que o banco de dados ficasse incorporado na aplicação, de forma que ela pudesse ser executada sem estar conectada a nenhum servidor?

Uma boa abordagem é o [SQL Server LocalDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh510202.aspx). Ele é idêntico ao SQL Server Express e usa as configurações do Entity Framework idênticas, da mesma forma.

Projetos ASP.NET MVC5 normalmente são criados com o LocalDb sendo usado por padrão.

> E como eu transportaria os dados do banco de dados para esta nova solução?

Usando o [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/mt238290.aspx).

Utilize [o assistente de migração](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssma/).

[Aqui tem o plugin do MySQL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42657).

Comment: Obrigado, Cigano! Acho que é a opção mais adequada mesmo. Sabe me dizer se, ao criar um arquivo de instalação, posso integrar este recurso? Ou o cliente teria que instalar a parte?

Comment: Pode. [A ideia está aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15867103/1314276).

Comment: Valeu Cigano! Mais uma vez me ajudando muito!

Comment: Cigano, tua ideia deu muito certo no meu computador. Ele cria uns arquivos .mdf e tudo funciona bem, até no instalador. Entretanto, quando eu instalo em outro PC, a princípio dá um erro falando que não consegue conectar no SQLServer. Eu instalei o arquivo SQLLOCALDB.MSI e o erro mudou. Diz que não consegue criar o arquivo pois ele já foi criado... Tem alguma dica de como fazer ele funcionar com a instalação em qualquer computador?

Comment: Você se certificou que o LocalDb está instalado em outro computador? [Aqui tem o instalador em separado](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=42299), para 32 e 64 bits.

Answer (score 6):

A solução normalmente é usar o SQLite. Ele é um banco de dados incorporado e costuma atender a maioria das necessidades das aplicações, principalmente se não há acesso direto vindo de máquinas diferentes. Note que o acesso indireto funciona bem sem problemas, o que é normal em aplicações web ou que possuem um servidor de aplicação (*middleware* ou algo do tipo).

Ele atende grandes volumes de dados e acessos muito bem. Só teria problemas se tiver uma quantidade muito grande de escritas longas efetivamente simultâneas.

Existe *driver* oficial para Entity Framework disponível.

Veja [quando usar o SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101).

Obviamente que existem outras soluções possíveis se não quiser um banco de dados incorporado, como apresentado em outras respostas. Nelas haverá a conexão com um servidor, mesmo que ele não esteja remoto.

O transporte de dados se dá de forma tradicional. Ou usa um software cliente, possivelmente GUI, igual de qualquer outro banco de dados, e tem bastante opção, ou faz programaticamente, nesse caso claro que teria que fazer uma conexão com o banco de dados não incorporado para ler os dados que serão escritos no SQLite, ou teria que se conectar a um serviço seu que forneça os dados (conectando no servidor).

Answer (score 1):

Existe opções de instalação do MySQL diretamente no Android, transformando-o num Server.
Uma uma boa opção seria migrar seu banco para o MariaDB (versão OpenSource do MySQL) e usar o :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.mariadb

Answer (score 0):

O fato é saber se você realmente precisa persistir/salvar esses dados. Se sim, terá que ser em algum lugar. Essa parte é ontem toma-se a decisão sobre persistência.

Muitas vezes, usar um banco de dados simples como o MySQL é mais vantajoso - como simples e rápida implementação - do que tentar uma solução mais "criativa".

Então a pergunta é: você precisa persistir dados?

Se sim, qual vantagem você enxerga em não ter um banco de dados? Qual problema você irá resolver não tendo um serviço de persistência como um MySQL?

Se não, pode-se partir para uma solução *In Memory*, como instanciar um `System.Data.DataSet`, nele criar todas as tabelas e relacionamentos que sua aplicação precisa. Então fazer um primeiro *seed* de dados para sua aplicação começar a funcionar. Essa é uma opção onde, caso sua aplicação seja reciclada, todos os dados serão limpos e iniciará do zero.

Importante também considerar que sua aplicação já existe e já está funcionando com um banco de dados. Vale a pena remove-lo? O ROI - retorno de investimento - é interessante? Pois remover um banco de dados, já implementado com EF, irá custar algumas horas do desenvolvedor para a adaptação.

Comment: Oi Thiago! Os dados são apenas para consulta. Ela ainda não foi instalada no cliente e estou querendo evitar instalar e configurar o banco de dados. Porém, como os dados já estão no MySQL gostaria de uma forma simples de transportá-los. Eu já vi algumas abordagens parecidas, mas nunca utilizei...

Comment: @FelipeBulle, use um banco de dados local. Os da [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150796/3825) do Cigano são bem convenientes.