# Banco de dados para dispositivos móveis

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite, mobile, desempenho, escalabilidade

Eu estou criando um aplicativo mobile e preciso usar um banco de dados para guardar os dados do usuários. Já pensei em SQLite, porém não é recomendado usá-lo em sites com mais de 100 mil requisições por dia, e caso o meu aplicativo tenha esse número de requisições, tenho medo do banco de dados ter algum erro ou algo do tipo.

Caso eu escolha o SQLite como banco de dados, eu posso trocar por outro banco de dados depois? E vocês podem me sugerir algum banco de dados diferente do SQLite que permita mais de 100 mil requisições por dia?

Comment: _"não é recomendado usa-lo em sites com mais de 100 mil requisições por dia"_ Achei meio arbitrária essa medida. Se for essencialmente leitura, não vejo problema nenhum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## O SQLite aguenta mais do imagina

Sua pergunta parte de uma premissa falsa. Primeiro isso é um valor pensado há uns 10, 15 anos atrás e foi bem, bem conservador, e não considera técnicas adequadas para aumentar essa capacidade. O SQLite melhorou muito de lá pra cá, o hardware melhorou (SSD, NVRAM chegando), pensou-se em melhores técnicas, e na prática sempre pôde mais.

Acho uma ingenuidade postarem esse valor, porque a capacidade nem pode ser medida dessa forma, tem várias premissas falsas nessa informação, e pior não terem atualizado.

Note que a página oficial está falando de servidor web que tem acesso concorrente e não de dispositivo móvel que nem costuma ter acesso concorrente. Na verdade a página fala que apenas 1% dos **websites** não são adequados. Então é outra premissa falsa.

Minha experiência é que na verdade 0,1% não são adequados para o SQLite (considerando todos, até os que nem um DB precisa), se usado do jeito correto. Você acha que será um dos 1% sites de maior sucesso do mundo? Isso quer dizer que você será um dos 20 ou 30 maiores sites brasileiros. Mesmo que um dia isso aconteça, terá tanto dinheiro vindo desse site que poderá contratar os melhores profissionais e comprar as melhores ferramentas para resolver seu problema.

Mesmo os bancos de dados mais sofisticados costumam precisar de ferramentas auxiliares, técnicas adequadas para aguentar. Esse site que está usando agora é um dos 30 mais acessados do mundo. Ele usa SQL Server, mas a capacidade de atender tudo isso não é porque o SQL Server é excelente, é porque os engenheiros que cuidam do site são excelentes. Tem site bem menor que usou SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, e outras coisas e abriu o bico. Por que? Quem fez não sabia o que estava fazendo. Sem entender como as coisas funcionam qualquer ferramenta pode ser a errada.

Veja mais sobre [onde pode ser usado de verdade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101).

## Trocar o DB

Sempre pode trocar o banco de dados, mas duvido que um dia seja preciso mesmo que use o SQLite no servidor web (só não posso garantir em todos cenários). Se for usar em mobile nunca terá que mudar, até porque o hardware de um celular não aguenta fazer tanta operação assim, o SQLite é menor dos seus problemas. Mas imagino que só está falando isso por achar que terá milhares de conexões em um dispositivo móvel. E é mais uma premissa falsa.

Se você está achando que as pessoas vão instalar o MySQL, Oracle, etc. nos seus celulares, está muito enganado. Não que não possa, mas isso é uma loucura que eu nunca vi alguém fazendo a não ser para experimento.

## Outros bancos de dados

Como já dito o SQLite pode atender milhões de requisições por dia se usado corretamente. Isso é mais do que quase todos sites do mundo precisam. Mas se **no servidor** quiser outro DB, e até existem razões para isso, mas não porque o SQLite não é bom, o mais usado para web é o MySQL, embora muitas pessoas estão preferindo o MariaDB que é um *fork* do MySQL.

Também pode usar outros bancos relacionais ou não, mas a decisão da ferramenta correta passa por uma análise profunda de gente muito experiente para acertar. Se está com dificuldade com algo tão básico, o melhor é ir pelo mais simples (SQLite) e contratar gente especializada quando precisar de algo sofisticado.

É o que eu falo sempre, as pessoas precisam aprender como as coisas funcionam, verificar por conta própria, e não acreditar no que está escrito por aí, a maior parte da informação disponível na internet está errada. Porque existem poucas informações canônicas, e mesmo essas podem estar erradas, como é o caso, e existem cópias da informação canônica deturpadas, como um telefone sem fio.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Como o AP vai usar localmente, SQLite é ideal pra ele. Agora, em um website, recomendo fortemente contra (a não ser que seja como o sqlite.org, que só faz uso do acesso de leitura – ainda assim, nesse caso é melhor gerar e servir páginas estáticas). O problema da concorrência já proíbe qualquer site com tráfego razoável e acesso à leitura/escrita de usá-lo. Mas mesmo sites com baixo tráfego estariam melhor servidos com outras soluções http://zenadmin.org/en/blog/post720.html . Discordo também da fantasiosa afirmação de que apenas 20 sites brasileiros não estariam bem servidos com o SQLite.

Comment: @rodorgas imagino que desconheça a capacidade real do SQLite e da necessidade real da maioria dos sites. A capacidade de lietura dele chega ser melhor do que de muitos outros banco de dados. A capacidade de escrita é limitada, mas como ele escreve bem mais rápido que os demais bancos ele pode atender bem mais casos de escrito quase concorrentes. Eu não disse que apenas 20 site brasileiros não estariam bem servidor pelo SQLite. Falo da capacidade dele. E falo de uso adequado. As pessoas se surpreendem como esse site que está entre os 25 mais acessados do mundo rodam com tão pouco recurso.

Comment: O que estou falando é que se a engenharia for a correta a ferramenta importa menos. Tem vários, eu disse vários benchmarks que mostram como o SQLite é bem mais rápido que o MySQL e outros bancos de dados. Realmente precisa saber usá-lo direito para que haja alta concorrência, então claramente esse que você pegou é um caso de alguém que não sabe. Se tiver muita escrita **concorrente** ele não é adequado, mas a maioria dos sites tem bem pouca escrita. Pelo menos deveriam ter, se não tem ou cai em um caso que realmente precisa de algo mais potente ou cai no caso de ter sido mal feito.

Comment: O meu ponto é em cima disso. Se fizer bem feito o SQLite é muito adequado. Se fizer errado, e muita gente faz errado, aí a ferramenta começa importar mais. Você pode acreditar no que quiser, a minha experiência é essa. As pessoas subvalorizam a capacidade do SQLite e superdimensionam a necessidade que um site tem para escrita. O benchmark publicado é bem velho e não diz como foi feito.

Comment: Olha como o absurdo é grande. 100 mil requisições não são *page views*. Mas vou considerar que sejam. Isso é pouco mais de 1 por segundo do dia. Claro que tem momentos de uso maior. Se tem tanto acesso provavelmente a maior parte do conteúdo está em cache na memória. O acesso nele é igual ou melhor (ele tem bem menos cerimônia para acessar os dados) que outros bancos de dados. Se o site tem tanto acesso assim, ele deve ter outros mecanismo de cache que fazem o banco de dados sequer serem consultados com essa frequência.

Comment: Mesmo que tenha que acessar o banco de dados em disco, ele pode atender dezenas ou centenas de requisições por segundo. Muito mais do que está descrito no site. Se considerar a memória, pode atender milhares. Conhece quantos sites brasileiros que têm milhares de acessos por segundo? E nem falei de que o site pode ser fracionado em alguns servidores. É tão simples fazer tudo isso funcionar? Não. Mas com qualquer banco de dados não é simples. O SQLIte é o mais adequado para esses casos mais extremos? Não, mas ele aguenta bem se fizer tudo certo? Sim.

Comment: Quando vamos falar em escrita, que é raro em sites (é comum elas serem menos de 1% das leituras, tem casos de ser uma fração bem menor que essa), aí complica um pouco mais. Mesmo assim ele é capaz de suportar dezenas, centenas, e quem sabem chegar nos 4 dígitos se usar um *array* de SSD (sem contar a distribuição em servidores das várias partes de um site que provavelmente deve ser grande para ter tanto acesso). Não tem nada de fantasioso nisso. Reafirmo que não serve qualquer caso. Serve a imensa maioria dos casos, se souber o que está fazendo. Usar outro DB talvez seja otimização prematura.

Comment: Muitos sites tem mudanças ocasionais no conteúdo e nem precisam de banco de dados, estariam melhor servidos com uma ferramenta de geração de arquivos estáticos, como o jekyll. Mas se o site for um simples blog com um sistema de comentários, o SQLite já não é adequado. Se é possível? Claro que sim, é possível tbm fazer um sistema de comentários com fopen (esse sim um concorrente do SQLite) e escrever o backend em C++ CGI. Se é recomendável? Isso é mais subjetivo, eu não recomendo pq não é a ferramenta adequada pra isso. Mas tudo isso tá na página do projeto e a pergunta não é sobre uso em sites

Comment: É que a página do projeto é muito conservadora e é completamente fora da realidade. É bom que as pessoas saibam que pode usar em muito mais do que está lá. Eu recomendo porque é a ferramenta adequada para isso. Empatou.

Answer (score 1):

Sim. É possível trocar o banco de dados. Claro que tudo depende da arquitetura do seu aplicativo, da estrutura do banco de dados, localização do banco (cliente ou servidor).

Existem diversas banco de dados relacionais MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server ou bd NoSQL, como MongoDB, CouchDB, etc.

No caso de utilizar SQLite para as aplicações mobile, esta restrição de 100mil requisições são para acessos num mesmo banco, em concorrência. Observe que muitas aplicações mobile utilizam SQLite, no próprio celular do usuário do aplicativo, em outras palavras cada usuário teria seu proprio banco. Se este for o caso do seu aplicativo essa restrição você não precisa se preocupar com tanto com as restrições do SQLite. Se você está utilizando o SQLite em um servidor a qual todos os usuários irão utilizar em concorrência, eu sugiro então verificar essas alternativas de banco.