# Salvar o mesmo arquivo ao mesmo tempo em threads diferentes

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

No meu software tenho uma `thread` que a cada segundo atualiza o arquivo X. Este mesmo arquivo pode também ser atualizado mediante uma ação do usuário que será em outra `thread` (pode ser a qualquer momento).

A minha dúvida é: o que vai acontecer se ambas as `threads` tentarem salvar o arquivo X no exato mesmo tempo? Há como garantir que o arquivo seja atualizado em ambos os casos?

**Preciso garantir que o arquivo seja atualizado em ambos os casos. Deixar de atualizar o arquivo não é uma opção.**

Sei que pode ser bem raro de acontecer (no exato milésimo de segundo) duas `threads` tentarem salvar o mesmo arquivo ao mesmo tempo. Mas e se acontecer?

Atualmente estou utilizando o código abaixo para salvar os arquivos:

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, false))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(encrypted);
}
```

Comment: Acho que essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159342/o-que-%c3%a9-uma-condi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-corrida/159343#159343) tem alguma relação com a pergunta

Comment: Obrigado @Barbetta, vou ler!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O recurso que você deseja acessar/manipular (o arquivo) é único. Assim sendo é interessante que você centralize as operações em um objeto *singleton* que seja *thread safe*. Um modelo assim força a criação de uma fila FIFO de acesso ao recurso.

Note que *threads* aguardando acesso entrarão em *wait-state* - entretanto este é um preço pequeno a se pagar para guarantir atomicidade das operações.

Para um exemplo de *thread-safe singleton*, leia este artigo: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) (especificamente os tópicos 'Second version - simple thread-safety' e 'Fifth version - fully lazy instantiation').

Os códigos a seguir são cópias do conteúdo do artigo (para evitar eventuais links quebrados):

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Versão via inicialização estática:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return Nested.instance; } }

    private class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Não é uma resposta direta que faz o que deseja diretamente, mas é a resposta que você deveria seguir.

Tratar concorrência é difícil, fazer errado é muito fácil, então é melhor usar outro mecanismo que já faça isto. Recomendo o uso do [SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101).

Ou seja, as duas respostas aqui estão mandando fazer outra coisa :) Qual será mais adequada para o seu caso depende da necessidade que não foi adequadamente postada.