# Utilização de Banco de dados SQL sem programas externos

Tags: sql

Existe alguma forma de ao fazer uma aplicação, instalar um banco de dados no computador de uma pessoa, e nesse computador utilizar um banco de dados sem utilização SQL server ou qualquer coisa do gênero, sendo necessário apenas a aplicação para atualizar, deletar e inserir novos dados ?

Comment: O banco de dados é a "aplicação" (gerenciador de bando de dados) como um todo, ela que possui toda estrutura para manipular os arquivos daquela tecnologia específica. Se você vai usar um banco SQL Server, consequentemente precisa usar o SQL Server. Existem outros tipos de BD, por exemplo SQLite, que é apenas um arquivo, aí cada aplicação que usa, deve ou não ter a possibilidade de manipulá-lo, ex.: PHP, Android, Java, etc... A grosso modo é isso.

Comment: Sim, crie seu próprio banco SQL (scripts,  API, estrutura, ...). Na prática, se conseguir fazer, provavelmente não vai ser nem rápido nem seguro, então use um que já exista. Não estou dizendo que não seja capaz, apenas que é algo muito difícil, e os bancos de dados conhecidos que existem, tem uma equipe grande e altamente capacitada, ou seja, não é algo simples

Comment: Também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101